# Помогите найти ошибку. Js

Tags: javascript, alert, prompt

Мне надо написать программу, когда вводишь положительное число оно alert-ит положительное, когда отрицательное-отрицательное․

```
var n=prompt('Enter number');
var a='1'; b='-1';
if (a>b) {
    x=a;    
    alert('Polojitelnoe');
}else if(a<b) {
    x=b;
    alert('Otricatelnoe');
}else {
    alert(x);
}
```

Comment: какое число ты считаешь положительным? если ты вводишь `n`, почему в сравнении участвуют только `a` и `b`?

Comment: и откуда берется `x` в `else`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var n = +prompt('Enter number');
if (n > 0) {
  alert('Polojitelnoe');
} else if (n < 0) {
  alert('Otricatelnoe');
} else {
  alert('Nol\'');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var n = +prompt('Enter number');
if (n > 0) {
  alert('Положительное');
} else if (n < 0) {
  alert('Отрицательное');
} else if (isNaN(n)) {
  alert('вы ввели не число');
} else {
  alert('Ноль');
}
```